# how to 'zero' all variables at each loop iteration

Tags: matlab, initialization, zero

I have written a script describing a dynamic biological process in matlab; the input to which is a year of daily temperature values.The model runs for a year on this daily timestep carrying out different calculations required for the process.

I have thirty years of temperature data (matrix of size 365*30) and I intend to write a 'for loop' at the start of the script in order to use each year of daily data consecutively. I have about 5 variables that are the output from the script, which I intend to output to a txt/csv file at each iteration. My problem is that there are approximately 80 variables within the model and I would like to zero them all at each iteration of the outermost loop (the temperature input). I would like to do this in an efficient manner rather than having to individually zero all the variables. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have been looking at using the 'who' function to list all the variables and I'm thinking that it could be used somehow to zero  everything. I have tried letting x = who; which seems to produce a list of all the variables in inverted commas. But obviously; trying to let x = 0 after that just redefines x. I was also thinking of just using 'clear all' but I think this would really slow the model down as it would be 'starting from scratch' redefining all the variable at each loop?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not put all your variables in a struct maybe? Otherwise I guess this is a decent use case for `eval`

Comment: just include what you have tried so far, in the post.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have 80 variables you are probably doing something strange. Consider to combine them into vectors or arrays for example.

That being said, there are two situations I can think about:

1. You already initialize all your variables somewhere

In this case the solution is simple: move the initialization to the start of your outer loop.

1. You don't initialize anything (bad practice, especially if you are concerned about performance)

In this case you should put a function inside your loop, that only returns your output variables and not all these loose intermediate variables.

Perhaps a combination of these two methods can also apply, but really I would recommend not to use 80 different variables! And initialize any variable that you need to use.

A compact syntax to initialize scalars would be:

```
[a, b,c]  = deal(0);
```

Comment: @Dan I have never used the struct command before but I'll have a look. Not all the output variable will be of the same dimensions though, so that could be a problem?

Comment: @NKN Besides for indivually zeroing each of the variable names; and allowing x=who followed by trying to zero 'x'. I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: Many of my variables are vectors? The model is made up of various submodels/functions which dynamically interact. Most variables are initiated at the start of the model, while others as created as needed within the model. The problem is when I want to use a new year of input (temp data) I'm concerned that leaving the values in place from the previous year may result in mistakes as there are lots of cumulative variables being used.

Comment: I know I can simply initialise everything as zero outside the outermost for loop; I was just hoping that there might be a more efficient approach that I hadn't thought of. The 'deal function looks useful.

Comment: @matlab_newby Judging from your comments, I think putting the relevant code in a function seems to be the way to go. Each time a function is called it gets its own workspace so there is no 'pollution' from the previous time the code is ran. Try `help function` or `doc function` if you are not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I was shying away from it as I thought that I would have to list each of the variables as 'input' for the function. But I suppose if I can save them down as some sort of list using the who function, then I could use that list as the 'input' right?

Comment: @matlab_newby that is indeed possible, but keep in mind that a clear might have better performance. I suppose you can just try.